# С чем может быть связан малый прирост производительности от увеличения числа потоков?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, производительность, amd

Работаю в Geant4 - это такой пакет для моделирования взаимодействия элементарных частиц с веществом, разработанный в CERN. Весь код в нём открыт, находится в свободном доступе. Грубо говоря, это набор библиотек, написанных на языке C++. Geant4 поддерживает мультитрейдинг.

В общем, запускал я ради теста одну и ту же задачу на слабом ноутбуке и на сильном. Вычисления ведутся на процессоре. Я не помню точно что за процессор на слабом ноутбуке, сейчас его нет под рукой, но это довольно новый Core i3 с базовой частотой 2 ГГц и L3 кэш 3 или 4 Мб, 2 физических и 4 логических ядер. Второй это Ryzen 7 4800h с базовой частотой 2.9 ГГц, и 8 Мб L3 кэша, 8 физических и 16 логических ядер. В общем, первый справился с задачей за 16 минут 44 секунды, а второй всего лишь за 5 минут 40 секунд. То есть прирост оказался даже чуть меньше, чем в 3 раза, хотя количество ядер отличается в 4 раза, не говоря уже о тактовой частоте. Та же задача на сильном ноутбуке, запущенная на 4 потоках посчиталась за 12 минут 30 секунд.
У меня возникает вопрос из-за чего прирост производительности оказался таким слабым? Я ожидал прирост минимум в 4 раза, так как на сильном ноутбуке ещё и тактовая частота выше. Может ли быть проблема в нехватке L3 кэша? Или это плохая оптимизация под много поточность? Или вовсе другая причина? Хотя вроде они заявляют о хорошей линейности, на сколько я понял:
https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Geant4/MultiThreadingTaskForce
https://indico.cern.ch/event/781244/contributions/3251900/attachments/1782717/2901032/Multithreading.pdf
Хотя, как я понял, в тесте на Intel Xeon Phi, тест сначала шёл в однопоточном режиме и показывал хорошую линейность от числа задействованных физических ядер. Но в моём случае в обоих случая задействовано максимальное число потоков.

Если я допустил ошибки или поставил не те метки, подскажите где ошибки или какие метки надо поставить.

Если тему не закроют, то вечером выложу результаты ещё одного небольшого теста с графиками.

Comment: Да нормальный прирост. Он никогда не будет строго пропорционален частоте процессора и количеству ядер/потоков, всегда будет меньше.

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы посмотрели htop'ом или чем-нибудь похожим на загрузку ядер во время работы программы. Они точно всё время загружены все и на 100%? Если нет, то, может, ввод-вывод?

Comment: CrazyElf, мне он совсем не нравится. Ниже я оставил комментарий по этому поводу и ссылку на результаты пары тестов.

Answer (score 5):

Есть тысячи причин, которые могут влиять на это все.

Самое первое - никто не отменял [закон Амадала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0). Грубо говоря, чем больше кода, который нельзя распараллелить, тем меньше будет ускорение. И рост ускорения будет даже не линейный.

второе - у Вас в сравнении процессоры разных производителей. А так как код можно заточить под команды конкретного процессора, особенности контроллера памяти, то разница может быть существенная. Когда то давно на AMD медленнее работал Word, так как использовал арифметику, которая работала быстрее на Intel.

третье - процессор далеко не самый важный критерий. Объем памяти или диск часто могут сильно повлиять на ситуацию. Хотя даже банальный антивирусник может такого натворить, что уххх.

Дальше. Есть такая штука, как тротлинг - это когда процессор или другая часть ноутбука/копьютера перегревается и понижается частота/скорость работы. И потом в тестах первые пять минут выигрывает одна конфигурация, а спустя два часа наряженной работы, ситуация меняется кардинально. Вот сейчас такое происходит с видеокартами nvidia rtx3080 - многие видеокарты зависали под нагрузкой и свежие драйвера просто [понизили производительность](https://dtf.ru/hard/220438-nvidia-priznala-problemy-so-stabilnostyu-geforce-rtx-3080-i-vypustila-drayver-kotoryy-ispravil-situaciyu) ... - тестируйте:)

Comment: Я провёл 2 теста, нагружая постепенно все потоки на обоих ноутбуках. Слабый ноутбук, работая на частотах около 1990 МГц на 4 потоках проигрывает всего в 2 - 3 раза сильному, который работает в 16 потоков на вдвое больших частотах. Слабый ноутбук в 1 потоке выигрывает в 1.5 - 2 раза у сильного. Ниже ссылка с графиками этих тестов.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrGaJkDBp4k9yEY6NE25GZqudIA3iKCO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: какой именно intel i3 используется? Хотя если посмотреть на то, то слабый ноут на одно ядро выигрывает в два раза у сильного, но при этом у сильного в 4 раза больше ядер, то и получается, что на полной загрузке всех ядер, сильный выиграет в два раза. То есть, распараллеливание работает отлично.

Comment: Core i3 6006u, я подписал там. Слабый ноут работает на максимальной частоте в 2 ГГц, сильный на базовой 2.9 но при расчётах бустится до 4 ГГц. Разве это не сильный должен был на 1 ядре уже в 2 раза выигрывать? Почему у сильного после 8 потоков почти перестаёт расти производительность? Как будто он сначала загружает все физические ядра, а потом 1 ядро, работая в 2 потока почти не даёт прирост.

Comment: Ваш график не доступен. Загрузите на какой то сайт для картинок."Почему у сильного после 8 потоков почти перестаёт расти производительность?" - ну так потоки дутые:)

Comment: Загрузил на первый попавшийся в поисковике сайт (тут 5 ссылок)
https://ibb.co/4dyzvTk
https://ibb.co/4gVwS3h
https://ibb.co/jWsbSrn
https://ibb.co/mtD0TYr
https://ibb.co/8DytrF2
"ну так потоки дутые" если это так, то это плохие новости для меня. Хотя почему-то на 8 потоках пишет, что проц загружен ровно только на 50%

Comment: загрузка в процентах в случае винды считается очень просто - в параллель запускается псевдо задача idle, которая ничего не делает. И дальше смотрим, сколько она может скушать проца. так и вычисляется загрузка.  Надо понимать, как появились эти "ядра-потоки". В свое время на интел процах АЛУ было очень слабое. и отдел постоянно пинали. Они поднапряглись и сделали его крутым. И теперь конвеер не мог загрузить АЛУ на 100%. поставили два конвеера и теперь наступило равновесие (не сразу конечно). Но есть такие задачи, которые сильно грузят АЛУ - тут плохо. Как дела у АМД - я не знаю.

Comment: Ну, у меня линукс. На слабом ноуте тоже линукс, но на виртуальной машине. Вообще говорили, что вроде как новые процессоры от AMD могут выполнять больше операций за такт, а в реальной задаче получилось, что 1 на 1 ядро от AMD проигрывает ядру от Intel, которое ещё и работает на меньших частотах. Ладно, спасибо. Попробую на форуме CERN найти ответ или задать вопрос. Там человек пишет о подобной проблеме, но уже с 2 процами от Intel. Правда там один xeon, а другой i5. Xeon выигрывает, но у него размеры кэшей сильно больше в сравнении с i5.

Comment: на одном ядре разница может быть просто из за того, что в коде есть условие типа "если интел, то вот так считаем, а если амд - так"

Comment: Это проблема может решиться оптимизацией кода под AMD, если проблема действительно в этом? Или в таком случае просто сами процессоры AMD на деле менее эффективны? И может ли это быть проблемой компилятора или там ядра Linux, например?

Comment: сложно сказать. я то и кода не видел в глаза.

Comment: Кода там огромное количество. Я провёл тесты процессоров в AIDA64, сильный ноутбук их все выигрывает в производительности на 1 ядро. Также провёл тесты памяти и в задержке памяти сильный проигрывает. 80 - 100 нс против 73 нс у слабого. Соответственно, и тайминги памяти у сильного выше. Не знаю, может ли это быть причиной проигрыша в производительности на 1 ядро при вычислении моей задачи. Также провёл тест на компиляцию проекта в однопоточном режиме и сильный опять проиграл. Хочу попытаться исправить ситуацию при помощи оптимизирующего компилятора от AMD https://developer.amd.com/amd-aocc/

Answer (score 0):

Проблему я давно решил, но думаю, что нужно ещё сюда на всякий случай отписаться. Виноват в плохой производительности я сам, ибо создал отладочную сборку джеанта. Когда я это понял и пересобрал в релизе, производительность возросла в несколько раз. Тестировал на одной из задач, скорость возросла примерно в 7.5 раз.